# Testing approach Chi Square vs Mann Whitney

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am looking to understand the best approach to determine if students in one school performed better on a quiz than another. In this scenario the quiz has five questions and only whole points are awarded, giving 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, & 5 as the only possible results.

The results:

```
| score | school_a | school_b |
|-------|----------|----------|
| 0     | 150      | 175      |
| 1     | 50       | 40       |
| 2     | 30       | 30       |
| 3     | 20       | 15       |
| 4     | 5        | 10       |
| 5     | 80       | 90       |
```

Given the non-normality of the distribution it seems like the Mann-Whitney test would be appropriate, but because scores are integers I am concerned that the ties may cause issues. Should I instead treat the scores as categorical variables and perform a chi-square test instead?

Is there another approach I should be considering instead?

Comment: A plain chi-square will ignore the ordering of the categories, making it hard to establish the question of interest. Can you explain more about the sense in which you intend "better"?

Comment: If you want to be theoretically safe, you could use ordinal regression with Score as the dependent variable and School as the independent variable.  Unfortunately I don't have this published anywhere, but at least for the two-sample case, Mann-Whitney follows the results of ordinal regression closely for this kind of data.  Just be sure to use a procedure for MW that accounts for ties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mann-Whitney (also two-sample Wilcoxon test):** Data are

```
a = rep(0:5, c(150, 50, 30, 20, 5, 80))
b = rep(0:5, c(175, 40, 30, 15, 10, 90))
summary(a)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.000   0.000   1.000   1.761   4.000   5.000 
 summary(b)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.000   0.000   1.000   1.764   4.250   5.000
```

The means and medians look very nearly the same for the two schools.
The formal test has P-value $0.6723 > 0.05$ so the difference is not
significant at the 5% level. For samples as large as these, the implementation of the Wilcoxon rank sum test in R, reports no difficulty
handling ties.

```
 wilcox.test(a,b)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  a and b
W = 61350, p-value = 0.6723
alternative hypothesis: 
   true location shift is not equal to 0
```

**Chisquared test of homogeneity of probabilities:** Counts are

```
f.a = c(150, 50, 30, 20, 5, 80)
f.b = c(175, 40, 30, 15, 10, 90)
MAT = rbind(f.a, f.b);  MAT
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
f.a  150   50   30   20    5   80
f.b  175   40   30   15   10   90
```

I agree with @Glen_b that the Wilcoxon test is best here, because the issue seems to be which school had the higher scores overall.
However, the chi-squared test will test whether the probabilities of getting
individual scores 0 through 5 are substantially the same at the two
schools. No difference between the two distributions is found.

```
chisq.test(MAT)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 5.1107, df = 5, p-value = 0.4025
```

**Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of of differences in CDFs:**

This is a test to see if there is a substantial difference
between the empirical CDFs (ECDFs) of the two samples.
To make an ECDF, sort the data and plot a stairstep function
that increases by $1/n,$ where $n$ is the sample size, at each
data value. If there are $k$ tied observations at a point, then
jump up by $k/n.$ Here are the ECDFs of for the two schools,
blue for a and orange for b.

```
plot(ecdf(a), col="blue", lwd=2)
lines(ecdf(b), col="orange", lty="dotted", pch="o")
```

[image]

The test statistic $D$ of the K-S test is the maximum vertical
distance between the two ECDFs. Again here, no significant
difference is found. For your data, this test may be considered an alternative
to the chi-squared test.

```
ks.test(a,b)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  a and b
D = 0.03835, p-value = 0.9605
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test(a, b) : 
   p-value will be approximate in the presence of ties
```

Comment: +1.  The only thing I might add is that looking at bar plots of the frequencies might be helpful: `Y= factor(c(a,b)); Group = c(rep("A", length(a)), rep("B", length(b))); library(lattice); histogram(~ Y | Group, nlayout=c(1,2), col="darkgray")`